# 'x' must be numeric ERROR in R while trying to create a Leaf and Stem display

Tags: r, plot, stem

I am a beginner at R and I'm just trying to read a text file that contains values and create a stem display, but I keep getting an error. Here is my code:

```
setwd("C:/Users/Michael/Desktop/ch1-ch9 data/CH01")
gravity=read.table("C:ex01-11.txt", header=T)
stem(gravity)
    **Error in stem(gravity) : 'x' must be numeric**
```

The File contains this:

'spec_gravity'
0.31
0.35
0.36
0.36
0.37
0.38
0.4
0.4
0.4
0.41
0.41
0.42
0.42
0.42
0.42
0.42
0.43
0.44
0.45
0.46
0.46
0.47
0.48
0.48
0.48
0.51
0.54
0.54
0.55
0.58
0.62
0.66
0.66
0.67
0.68
0.75

If you can help, I would appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: Study the problem from the perspective of the class or mode of `gravity`. Dataframes are not of mode numeric. They are lists. You need to access a dataframe column ... which should be described in any introductory text.

Comment: There may be a typo in your read.table unless you copied and pasted it here incorrectly.   One would have expected `read.table("C:/path/to/your/file/ex01-11.txt", header=T)` instead of a filename with a ":" in it.  It's possible that `gravity` is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gravity` is a data frame. `stem` expects a vector. You need to select a column of your data set and pass to `stem`, i.e.

```
## The first column
stem(gravity[,1])
```